# How to localize country names in phrases?

Tags: translation, machine-translation

I want to localize phrases like "Places in {country name}" where the (already localized) country name is dynamically obtained according to the ISO country code.

The problem is that for some country names, an article must be prepended:

- Places in **the** United States (`en`)

Sometimes in plural form, male or female, capitalized or not:

- Lugares en **los** estados unidos (`es`)
- Lugares en **las** Maldivas (`es`)

The article might even have to be declined according to the case (nominative, dative etc) of the country name in the phrase:

- Orte in **der** Schweiz (`de`)
- Wir fahren in **die** Schweiz (`de` for "we go to Switzerland")

Or we even might might a different preposition:

- Orte **auf den** Malediven (`de`, using "auf" instead of "in" because the Maldives are islands)

Is there either a library or a good set of rules (e.g. regular expression based) that one could use to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open because it is on-topic for this site. As far as I can tell the question is about generating noun phrases or prepositional phrases, so basically computational linguistics.

Comment: The Maldives aren’t an island, but a large group of islands. And as is often the case when an island or archipelago is a sovereign state, there’s a lot of vacillation between ‘on’ and ‘in’ in languages like German. Also don’t forget there are languages where it’s the name, not the article, that changes; in Finnish, for instance, the Maldives are _Malediivit_, and ‘in the Maldives’ would be _Malediiveilla_ (on) or _Malediiveissa_ (in). I’ve left out ‘places’ here, since you also need to know which case _that_ should be in.

Comment: I think you need to do one language at a time. You can't just do them using all the same rules.

Answer (score 2):

The article's presence or absence can easily be included as part of the substitution.  I don't have a solution for the when declension and/or change of pronoun is needed.